# How to record audio in Clipchamp?

Tags: windows, video-editing, audio-recording

So I'm trying to use this Microsoft's Clipchamp app to edit my video to which I want to add some my comments - record audio

But I can't find the way to do, this app only suggests camera+audio recording or screen+audio, I want just audio

[image]

[image]

At least this app supports webm, I tried Adobe Premiere and others, they could not add the video

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to have your voice recorded for the narration with the mic, try using Windows’ built-in Sound Recorder. From there you can record your voice, save said audio file, and then import and drop your saved audio file into Clipchamp. It truly works. Go ahead and give it a try.